# Is there a better way to have my computer opponent to generate a word of (3 > random length <= 7)?

Tags: java, random

I have implemented the following method to do as such, but I still find that a lot of the times it produces only a three letter word. Once in a great while, it does do a four letter, five letter, etc. word, but it is still most three letters. Is there any other way that can guarantee a true random, to where it's always changing and never repetitive? Please let me know if I need to clarify myself further. This is for a Scrabble-like game, in which I am building for a final project in my Java programming class. TIA!

Here is my code:

```
//METHOD - getWordFromComputer
public static String getWordFromComputer(char[] let)
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    rand.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());
    String word = "";
    boolean done = false;
    while(!done)
    {
        word = "";
        boolean[] used = new boolean[7];
        int lettersUsed = 0;
        int max = 7;
        int min = 3;
        int size = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;//Code provided by: mkyong.com
        while(lettersUsed < size)
        {
            int i = rand.nextInt(7); //Random from 0 to 6 (7)
            if(!used[i]) { //The current index hasn't been chosen yet
                used[i] = true;
                lettersUsed++;
                if(let[i] != '_') {
                    word += let[i];
                } else {
                    word += letters[rand.nextInt(26)];
                }
            }
        }
        if(wordVerify(word)) {
            done = true;
        }
    }
    return word;
}
```

Comment: if you think you will forever and always get unique random number which is greater than 3 and less then or equals to 7 then you are wrong, at one point of time all probability will be exhausted and this approach is not good to go, analyse the use case first and think about the problem statement before jumping into finding the solution or writing code.

Comment: If you want more than 3 letters, `min` need to be bigger than 3, or move `+ 1` out of `nextInt` `rand.nextInt(max - min) + 1 + min`

Comment: mkyong is dumb because Java (since 1.7) now has `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min,max+1)`

Comment: @MarkJeronimus, they had that solution too. I utilized it at one point in time, but it seemed like I was getting a worse random than the code I currently have.

Comment: @Guy, I am aware. It’s just that it does the minimum A LOT and rarely showcases anything other than that.

Comment: @ShankarSaranSingh, I know exactly what the problem statement is and what I need to have corrected. I’m just looking for a better way. I’m fully aware that a random should have repetition every so often, but it occurs an awful lot before it hits higher than a word containing three characters.

Comment: `ThreadLocalRandom` uses `Random` internally so it cannot be worse.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus, I have now utilized ThreadLocalRandom instead. I forgot to add that pesky +1 for inclusion. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off of other previous answers, the best algorithm I have written to accomplish this and obtain a better randomness was the following:

```
/** METHOD - getWordFromComputer*/
public static String getWordFromComputer(char[] let) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    rand.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());
    String word = "";
    boolean done = false;
    while(!done) {
        word = "";
        boolean[] used = new boolean[7];
        int lettersUsedCount = 0;

        //Generate random word length
        int max = 7;

        //RANGE 1 - Base of minimum
        int randomizedMinBase = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(3, 6 + 1);

        //RANGE 2 - Randomized minimum from Range 1 value to number 6.
        int randomizedMin2 = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(
                randomizedMinBase, 6 + 1);

        //RANGE 3 - Randomized minimum from Range 2 value to number 6
        int randomizedMin3 = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(
                randomizedMin2, 6 + 1);

        //FINAL RANGE - Range from randomizedMin3 to 7
        int mainMin = randomizedMin3;
        int size = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(mainMin, max + 1);

        while(lettersUsedCount < size) {
            int index = rand.nextInt(7); //Random from 0 to 6 (7)
            if(!used[index]) {//The current index hasn't been chosen yet
                used[index] = true;
                lettersUsedCount++;
                if(let[index] != '-') {//Use a regular tile
                    word += let[index]; 
                } else {//Update a blank tile
                    char randLetter = gameTiles[rand.nextInt(26)];
                    computerScore -= valueOfLetter(randLetter);
                    word += gameTiles[rand.nextInt(26)];
                }//End else
            }//End boolean if
        }//End while

        /* Verify if a word to ensure the computer always generates a
         * playable word
         */
        if(wordVerify(word)) {
            done = true;
        }//End if
    }//End boolean while
    return word;
}//End getWordFromComputer method
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you're generating words of a random length, and trying if it's valid. The probability of a short word being valid is just that much higher. The solution is to generate a length once and then enter the `while` loop that tries different words until one is valid.

Comment: That makes sense! I’ll try that when able!

Comment: I had written a new algorithm in late November that solved my problem and implements the solution to the issue I was having in which you found in my previous code. I have posted my updated code below. I can comment on things if you and/or others have questions on why I did certain things a certain way. It is truly a unique algorithm. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't state your `wordVerify()` function, which could be the reason why your word lengths don't have the same probability.

You can implement your function in a simpler way using `Collections.shuffle()` and Java 8 streams:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Test
{
    static final List<Character> LETTERS = List.of('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i');
    static final int MIN_LENGTH = 3;
    static final int MAX_LENGTH = 7;
    static final Random r = new Random();

    public static String getWordFromComputer()
    {
        int len = r.nextInt(MAX_LENGTH-MIN_LENGTH+1)+MIN_LENGTH;
        List<Character> shuffled = new ArrayList<>(LETTERS); 
        Collections.shuffle(shuffled);
        shuffled = shuffled.subList(0, len);
        return shuffled.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining());        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {System.out.println(getWordFromComputer());}
    }
}
```

P.S.: This does not guarantee that a word never repeats, which is in fact impossible because there is only a finite number of words of a given length. However by generating the set of all possible such words beforehand and then shuffling that set and taking out words one by one, you could guarantee that repetition does not occur for a very long time. However for your Java programming class I am not sure if they expect no repetition ever as that is in violation of your other requirement, that it is truely random, as true randomness can in fact produce repetitions.

Comment: My wordVerify method is implemented, I just forgot to include that in my question. I will update this when I have more time. Thank you!

Comment: No need to continue on with this as Mark has found my problem. Thank you for your help, however!